# Sortable jQuery UI to replace the element position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the grid order using jQuery UI Sortable.
The way that I am trying to drag the elements over the grid but assume that If I drop 1 to 12, I need top get the grid 12 to 1 automatically instead of default sorting. How can we sort on this way?

[image]

```
$("div.reorder-photos-list").sortable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    start: function(event, ui) {

   },
 change: function(event, ui) {
     /*var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos');
     var index = ui.placeholder.index();
     console.log('Change ' + start_pos);*/

 },
 update: function(event, ui) {

   //alert(ui.placeholder.index());
   var start_pos = ui.item.index();
   console.log('Update ' + start_pos);

   var id = $(ui.item).attr('cur-id');
   var cp = $(ui.item).attr('cur-pos', start_pos+1);

   console.log("ID " + $(ui.item).attr('cur-id') + "Pos " + $(ui.item).attr('cur-pos'));

 }


   });
```

Comment: can you please show some code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the Answer,
Check on my JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/5fyqz9f6/1/

If anyone needs to make changes in order of a grid system it's useful.

reorder-photos-list = Main Div
col-md-4 = Loop Divs

In My JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var droppableParent;

    $('.reorder-photos-list .widget-user').draggable({
        revert: 'invalid',
        revertDuration: 200,
        start: function() {
            droppableParent = $(this).parent();
            droppableParent.addClass('being-dragged');
        },
        stop: function() {
            droppableParent.removeClass('being-dragged');
        }
    });

    $('.reorder-photos-list .col-md-4').droppable({
        hoverClass: 'drop-hover',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var draggable = $(ui.draggable[0]),
                draggableOffset = draggable.offset(),
                container = $(event.target),
                containerOffset = container.offset();

            //draggable.addClass('animated shake');

            setTimeout(function() {
                var pos = draggable.parent().index();
                var cid = draggable.attr('cid');
                var ctype = draggable.attr('ctype');
                var posFinal = pos + 1;
                var aUrl = "";

                alert("cid : " + cid + " pos : " + posFinal);



            }, 500);



            $('.widget-user', event.target).appendTo(droppableParent).css({
                opacity: 0
            }).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 200);

            draggable.appendTo(container).css({
                left: draggableOffset.left - containerOffset.left,
                top: draggableOffset.top - containerOffset.top
            }).animate({
                left: 0,
                top: 0
            }, 200);
        }
    });
});
```